# Detect when user clicks outside of textarea but not outside of element

Tags: jquery, click

I have a textarea, and a submit button. When a user clicks outside of the textarea a script is run, and if there is nothing in the textarea, it hides the submit button. However, I don't want it to be if you click outside of the textarea because when you click the submit button it runs the action, and hides the button. which it shouldn't. So I need to detect when the user clicks outside of the wrapper div of the textarea and submit button and run the script.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
     <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the 'target' property of the event, which will tell you which element was actually clicked on. You can then do a conditional statement to ensure that the submit button didn't dispatch the event.

jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.target

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $text = $("textarea.textarea"),
        $btn = $("input.submit");
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$text.is(e.target) && !$btn.is(e.target) && $text.val() == "")
            $btn.hide();
        else
            $btn.show();
    });
});
```

That is, bearing in mind that click events bubble up to the document but you can still determine the originally clicked element with `event.target`, on any click event that the document receives test whether the click was somewhere other than the textarea or button, and if so and the textarea is empty hide the button, otherwise show it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HpmDF/

Note that using classes to identify individual controls isn't the best plan, that's what id is for. If there can be more than one textarea and associated button you'll need a different solution.

P.S. Note also that you asked explicitly about "clicks" and that's what I've provided, but you need to allow for the user tabbing out via the keyboard...